# calling same function after timeout malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 tabSlideOut()
}

function tabSlideOut() {
  $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
  //----
});
```

Want call tabslideout hide after 3 second showing the success or error message so i call it after timeout ,

```
setTimeout(function () { tabSlideOut(); }, 3000)
```

but it malfunctioning it repeat hiding and showing again and again please any one can guide me to to do this

Comment: Sorry, but could you be more specific?

Comment: doubtful you want to initialize plugin each time with same options, does plugin not have `open` and `close` methods? Post link to plugin docs

Comment: In the tabSlideout function can you do the following: console.log("from tabSlideout",this); When you open the page in firefox with firebug installed and check what that value is when called on document ready and from timeout?

Comment: You don't have `setTimeout` inside the `tabSlideOut` function right?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, instead of setTimeout directly try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  tabSlideOut.call($(document));
},YOUR=TIMEOUT=IN=MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, don't merge pure js with jquery if you don't need it. Also you need to correct your syntax:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { 
       $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
           ....
       });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a hidden filed on your page.
when ever you call your function

```
 function tabSlideOut() {
  //check for the hidden field value
  //if it is initial value of the hidden field
  // add one in the initial value of the hidden filed
  // call the function
   $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
 //----

});
  //if not initial value
  //don't call your function
```